# Qwt Plot: How to reduce spacing between legend items

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I find that the spacing between the rows in the legend of a Qwt plot is quite large. I would like to fit more items in the legend without the need to scroll and without increasing the size of the legend.

Is there a way to reduce or remove the spacing between items in the legend?

EDIT:

Here is what I get

[image]

And here is what I want

[image]

Here is an example code showing how I add curves to the plot which are then shown in the legend. It does not exactly reproduce the above plot, but shows the principle:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QwtPlot* plot = new QwtPlot(this);
    setCentralWidget(plot);

    // Add curves
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve( "Curve " + QString::number(i) );
        curve->attach( plot );
        curve->setPen( Qt::blue, 2 );
        curve->setLegendAttribute( QwtPlotCurve::LegendShowLine );
    }

    // Add legend
    QwtLegend *legend = new QwtLegend();
    legend->setDefaultItemMode(QwtLegendData::Clickable); // make items clickable
    connect(legend, SIGNAL(clicked(const QVariant &, int)), this, SLOT(onLegendItemClicked(const QVariant &,int)) );        
    plot->insertLegend( legend, QwtPlot::LeftLegend );
}
```

If I remove the line

```
legend->setDefaultItemMode(QwtLegendData::Clickable);
```

the spacing between the legend items is reduced a bit (still not quite as reduced as I want it), but then the clicked(...) signal is not emitted when the item is clicked.

Any idea how to reduce the spacing without loosing the clickability?

Comment: show an image of what you get and another of what you want to get.

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]